# Azure AD B2C Signout does not invalidate the token

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We are using MSAL library  and invoking the end_session_endpoint url for logout, It is not invalidating the access token.
If we use the same token after logout, it still works. Any fix for the same.
Is there any particular way of doing the signout from web applications

Note: We see this issue in mobile as well with the library react-native-ios-android-appauth-b2c

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the logout to the correct B2C endpoint? Can you give us the endpoint URL?

Comment: "end_session_endpoint": "https://<tenantname>.xxx.xxx/<tenantname>.xxxx.xxx/oauth2/v2.0/logout?p=<PolicyName>"

Comment: The access tokens are bearer tokens, they are valid until they expire and there's no mechanism to invalidate them. Are you sure you're not talking about the client session?

Comment: What's the xxx.xxx in your url? Something like https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/logout?
p=b2c_1_sign_in
&post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faadb2cplayground.azurewebsites.net%2F ? Note that the 2 parts you masked are not identical!

Comment: It's possible you are confusing the access token with the session cookie or something similar to it. The end_session_endpoint will only clear the session.

Comment: Can you give me more details on Session Cookie and what will happen to session cookie on logout and can this be used for validation

Comment: The session cookie is not directly related to the access token. As explained, the access token cannot be invalidated or revoked. The endpoint you mentioned in the question will clear the B2C session cookie in the browser and the state on the B2C server, but will do nothing to the access token. Please provide more details, as it's not clear why you want to invalidate the access token. If you don't want it to be used anymore, just delete it and make sure no copies are persisted anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

That's as per the specification. Access tokens can't be revoked or invalidated.

It's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#access-tokens).

"Clients use access tokens to access a protected resource. An access token can be used only for a specific combination of user, client, and resource. **Access tokens cannot be revoked and are valid until their expiry.** A malicious actor that has obtained an access token can use it for extent of its lifetime. Adjusting the lifetime of an access token is a trade-off between improving system performance and increasing the amount of time that the client retains access after the user’s account is disabled. Improved system performance is achieved by reducing the number of times a client needs to acquire a fresh access token. The default is 1 hour - after 1 hour, the client must use the refresh token to (usually silently) acquire a new refresh token and access token."

Refresh tokens can be revoked.

Answer (score 1):

The access token cannot be invalidated. It's a bearer token, so it can be used until its expiry by anyone holding it.

In your case there's probably no need to invalidate the token at logout. You can simply delete it on your end, making sure it's not persisted anywhere.

The end_session_endpoint endpoint you mentioned will only clear the B2C session cookie in the browser and the user state on the B2C server, which are not directly related to the access token.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an endpoint to send (logout) the tokens into a blacklist cache system, like redis, and remain that key until it expires. Then check if the key exists in your cache before authentication.